# Highcharts: Grouped Timeline to show events grouped by Months

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-material

Has anyone managed to create a timeline chart where events are grouped over months similar to the image below?

[image: Image of monthwise timepline]

Currently, I see the following two kinds of timelines offered in highcharts but haven't found any documentation that talks about grouping events under a common month or heading

[image]

[image]

If someone can point me to a working jsfiddle or plunkr snippet that would be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in the timeline series yet.

Feel free to add your feature request using the following GitHub link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose